# Safari - Picture in Picture with Youtube playlist

Tags: safari, macos, youtube

I am working on a Mac OS Sierra 10.12.1 using the new Safari Picture in Picture functionality.

It works well for single Youtube videos but how can I keep watching videos on Youtube playlists?

Right now, I have to go back to Safari at the end of each video and reenabled Picture in Picture mode every time.

Answer (score 3):

Disable Adblocker to fix the p.i.p. playlist problem